# Samsung 950 SSD, Slow detection in BIOS on boot

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

When booting, the BIOS is unable to detect my Samsung 950 Pro, therefore not booting from it.

After some time it is detected, and I can set it as the first in the boot order in BIOS, and the system boots normally. (It is moved to the second priority when detected)

Anything I can do, so the drive is detected right when I power my computer?

**Harddisk**

- Name: NVMe Samsung SSD 950
- Firmware: 1B0QBXX7 (Latest, according to Samsung Magician) Driver:
- Latest download from Samsung website

**Motherboard**

- Name: Gigabyte Z97X-Gaming 3
- Firmware: F5 (05/30/2014)

**OS**

- Name: Windows 10 Pro
- Build: 14965 (Insider Preview)

EDIT
I have updated my Motherboard firmware to F7.
This does not solve the problem, but it seems like it has helped it a bit. It does not feel as the time for it to detect the drive is as long as it was before.

Comment: First: Update your BIOS. The latest beta version is F8d, but probably just go to the latest stable: F7.

Comment: Also, have you had this issue since you first put the drive in this computer, or did it work fine at first and then develop this problem later? Is this a clean install of Windows on this drive, or did you copy/upgrade from a different drive?

Comment: Have you tried connecting another SSD or HDD to the same SATA cable?  What happens if you try a different motherboard SATA port or cable?

Comment: @Bob the 950Pro is a M2 SSD, no SATA, so there are no cables.

Answer (score 0):

My problem have been fixed.
I ordered some more RAM, and after inserting these in the machine, so all 4 RAM slots are filled, there have been no delay detecting the disk and starts normally.